# Class Execption Error When Running ExecutorService in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, callable

I have an activity that uses AsyncTask to run a scan. During the doInbackground method of the AsyncTask I call a runnable class that implements Callable (I need to return something from the class) this class establishes socket connection with other hosts, if connection is success then it tries to resolve canonical name. And this hostname is what I want to get form the pool of threads. The issue I'm having is when I'm trying to get the return from resultList.

```
public List<Future<Node>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
public Future<Node> result = null;
```

This is the exception I'm getting. apparently when using for loop to loop through resultList to get results. there's a cast exception, as I'm trying to collect the wrong data.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.pctechtips.netdroid.Node
            at org.pctechtips.netdroid.activity.IpScanActivity$TaskScanNetwork.doInBackground(IpScanActivity.java:202)
            at org.pctechtips.netdroid.activity.IpScanActivity$TaskScanNetwork.doInBackground(IpScanActivity.java:156)
```

asynctask class

```
private class TaskScanNetwork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        static final int NUMTHREADS = 254;
        String hostname;
        String subnet = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf("."));
        int startIp = 1;
        int range = (numOfHost / NUMTHREADS); //range to be scanned by every thread
        int stopIp = startIp + range;
        List<Future<Node>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        Future<Node> result = null;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMTHREADS);
        static final int TIME_OUT = 1000;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            hostList.clear();
            Node node = new Node(ip, mac);
            hostList.add(node);
            scanProgress.setMax(numOfHost);
            scanProgress.setProgress((numOfHost * 10) / 100 ); //set progress bar at 10%
//            statusMsg.setText("Scanning " + subnet + ".0/" + cidr);
        }

        /* initialaze threads */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.v("BACKGROUND", "doInBackground stuff");
            for(int i = 0; i < NUMTHREADS; i++) {
                IpScanRunnable ipScan = new IpScanRunnable(subnet, startIp, stopIp);
                result = executor.submit(ipScan);
                resultList.add(result);
                startIp = stopIp;
                stopIp = startIp + range;
            }

            try {
                new Thread().sleep(TIME_OUT);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
            for(Future<Node> future : resultList) {
                try {
                    Log.v("NODE", future.get().getHostName());
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            executor.shutdown();

            publishProgress();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
            networkAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            networkTxtView.setText(subnet + ".0/ " + cidr);
            numOfHostTxtView.setText(hosts+"");
            scanProgress.setProgress(254);
        }
    }
```

runnable class

```
package org.pctechtips.netdroid.runnable;
import org.pctechtips.netdroid.Node;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class IpScanRunnable implements Callable {
    private List<Node> results;
    private static final String TAG = "IPSCANRUNNABLE";
    private final static int TIMEOUT = 1000;
    private final static int PORT = 7;

    private String subnet;
    private Integer startIp;
    private Integer stopIp;

    public IpScanRunnable(String subnet, int start, int stop) {
        this.subnet = subnet;
        this.startIp = start;
        this.stopIp = stop;
        results = new ArrayList();

    }

    @Override
    public List<Node> call() throws Exception {
        Socket socket = null;
        for(int i = startIp; i < stopIp; i++) {
            String ip = subnet + "." + i;
            socket = new Socket();
            try {
//                android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
                InetAddress ipAdd = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                byte[] ipBytes = ipAdd.getAddress();
                socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(ipBytes), PORT), TIMEOUT);
                String hostname = ipAdd.getCanonicalHostName();
                Node node = new Node(ip);
                node.setHostName(hostname);
                results.add(node);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){

            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public List<Node> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<Node> call()` returns list. When you submit callable to executor then it becomes `Future<List<Node>>` while your list expects `Future<Node>`

Java does not verify generic parameter at runtime so there is no error when you add `Future<List<Node>>` instead of `Future<Node>`. However, when you get it from the list and cast to `Node` then it fails.

Comment: so the declaration should be like this: List<Future<List<Node>>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        Future<List<Node>> result = null;

Comment: Declaration only is not enough :) You also have to change processing code which iterates over futures.

Comment: is it the same List<Future<List<Node>>> as List<Future>

Comment: I changed it to this, but still not working for(Future future : resultList) {
                try {
                    for (List<Node> nodes : future.get()) {
                        Log.v("NODE", "");
                    }
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

Comment: Yes but better to keep as much details as possible and give compiler more chances to catch something

Comment: Must be `for (Node mode : future.get())`

Comment: realize that call() method returns a List not individual nodes... anyway I changed it to for(Future<List<Node>> future: resultList) {
                try {
                    for(Node node: future.get()) {
                        Log.v("RESULT", node.hostName);
                    }
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } and run in debugger.. is not even entering to the inner for loop for some reasone

Comment: it may enter to inner loop only when some IpRunnable is completed